# Generate VFREEBUSY component in iCal file from Google calendar

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I am trying to generate an iCal file from Google Calendar (http://calendar.google.com) after updating events in calendar.
When I try to download the iCal from a url I always get following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150408
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150416
DTSTAMP:20150406T041534Z
UID:3rasel00g1mm5jb9vbovp5bdts@google.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20150404T171907Z
DESCRIPTION:TEST
LAST-MODIFIED:20150406T041101Z
LOCATION:TEST
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:TEST
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now instead of "VEVENT" I want to have "VFREEBUSY" component. How can I get that ?

I have tried options like enabling "Share only my free/busy information (Hide details)" in Google Calendar Sharing settings. But still I get the same "VEVENT" and not "VFREEBUSY" component.
I also set "Show me as:" as "Busy" in every event I created in calendar. But I never see "VFREEBUSY" component in iCal.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved. I should specify time when creating events, the Google Calendar will then generate VFREEBUSY component for each of the event.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved. I should specify time when creating events in calendar, the Google Calendar will then generate VFREEBUSY component for each of the event.